# angular js flexslider with one row of thumbnails

Tags: angularjs, flexslider

I am using the flexslider with angularjs, so the examples form the website with jquery are not really helpful. So I have implemented the slider:
HTML

```
<div>
     <flex-slider flex-slide="image in product.imagePaths track by $index" animation="slide" control-nav="thumbnails">
        <li data-thumb="{{imagesUrl}}{{image.thumbnail}}">
            <img ng-src="{{imagesUrl}}{{image.custom}}">
        </li>
     </flex-slider>
</div>
```

in the js I get an array of objects that consist of three strings each(paths for original, custom size and thumb)

and have overwritten CSS for size:

```
  .flexslider {
          width: 400px;
          height: 400px;
   }

        .flexslider .slides img {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
        }

  .flex-direction-nav a  {
      line-height: 40px;
    }
```

I have 12 thumbnails, clicking them works fine, does exactly what they are supposed to do; the problem is that they are all visible, shown on three rows. I have added the requested classes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/flexslider/flexslider.css" />
```

and scripts:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular-flexslider.js"></script>
```

don't know what else to do, and I find documentation (examples) for angular very poor. Can anyone please help? spent already a day on it...

**EDIT**
plunker for demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/gWtik8Q3qXhQjlyjhoRD

**SECOND EDIT**
ok, I have found a plunker with a working carousel for thumbnails, but it basically builds two flex sliders. is this the only way? when in the example on git (https://github.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider/blob/master/examples/thumbnail-controlnav.html) they use my version? plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/K4VBoSqCAFbr1Fps0JJr

Comment: You have a few dependencies that I do not want to miss. Would you put together a plunker for this question?

Comment: @BrianGerhards ok, have made one. you can find it in the post as edit

Comment: It does look like you need another carousel for your thumbnails. See this example, looks very similar to the one you found on Plunker http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html

Comment: @BrianGerhards - of course I have seen those examples. they are jquery examples. And that one is not similar at all. two totally different stories; I have added in my second edit the link from git where they implement it in angular like this

Comment: I am not quite understanding what you are looking for. Can you draw a picture of what you are looking for? https://wireframe.cc/ ... Despite the jQuery implementation or Angular implementation, you need a flexslider 'slider' DIV for your photos and a flex-slider 'carousel' for your thumbnails. It doesn't seem you can't, or rather shouldn't, combine these.

Comment: @BrianGerhards - don't think it needs a drawing. I want the thumbnails to be a carousel (one row with arrows left and right). I don't want to use jquery, I want to use angular. on the angular-flexslide there is an example similar to mine: https://github.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider/blob/master/examples/thumbnail-controlnav.html. implemented it doesn't do what it should. why?

Answer (score 2):

See the Plunker I created. This is a modification of your Plunker attached. Per the implementation, jQuery or not, you need to split the images and the thumbnail. http://plnkr.co/edit/kTSQuJfi5OmOSw6cU06x?p=preview

```
<div id="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div class="col-sm-12">

      <flex-slider slider-id="slider" flex-slide="image in prod.imagePaths track by $index" animation="fade" animation-loop="false" sync="#carousel" slideshow="false" control-nav="false" init-delay="100">
        <li>
          <img ng-src="{{image.custom}}">
        </li>
      </flex-slider>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <flex-slider slider-id="carousel" flex-slide="image in prod.imagePaths track by $index" animation="slide" animation-loop="false" item-width="210" item-margin="5" as-nav-for="#slider" slideshow="false" control-nav="false">
        <li>
          <img ng-src="{{image.thumbnail}}">
        </li>
      </flex-slider>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I am afraid we are running in circles. I have posted this example in the second edit. on their git page is an example (that I have also posted there) where it is done the way I did...my problem is that their example doesn't work...I don't want this workaround, when it can be done clean the way they did....

Comment: This is how it works. the flex-slide attribute provides the items that will be part of the slide. If you look at the source code, one slide is created, not two. You can try and implement custom code to generate a second slider that reads an additional attribute like flex-slide-thumbnail, but I would recommend against it at this time as you've spent over a day on this. For now, there is no native implementation for what you are looking for with such small amounts of code. You may be able to create a directive in Angular and save code in the html if this is your goal.

Comment: then why did they make this possible, and even posted it as an example on their git page? <flex-slider flex-slide="image in product.imagePaths track by $index" animation="slide" control-nav="thumbnails">
        <li data-thumb="{{imagesUrl}}{{image.thumbnail}}">
            <img ng-src="{{imagesUrl}}{{image.custom}}">
        </li>

Comment: They are not showing you how to code a slider for the thumbnails as well as the images in that example. Pull it into plunker and give it a go. They have a separate example with multiple sliders, similar to the jquery example.

Comment: I did give it a go when I found it and posted it here :)

Comment: With knowledge that you will likely need to write another slider for -slide-thumbnail or something like that, does that answer your question/concern? Flex-slide simply does not provide you with 2 sliders with one flex-slider tag, you need to create a separate slider as in the example above.

Comment: I am not sure if you are guessing or not. I cannot believe that they made a mistake on their git page with the implementation I have used (from their git page). and no, this doesn't answer my concern, since it was a solution I have found and posted in my question.